# Resolving cyclic dependency with one template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

This looks simple, but I have no good idea to solve this. Minimal example:

```
template<class T>
struct C {
    typename T::t var;
};

class B;
struct A : public C<B> {
    typedef int t;
};

struct B
{
    A a;
};

int main() { return 0; }
```

I know that it can be solved by giving C less of B:

```
template<class t>
struct C {
    t var;
};

struct A : public C<int> {
};
```

But this does not satisfy (especially because B has a lot of such typedefs and static functions I really need in C). Any better idea to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make `A` a template, then the following ought to work...

```
template<class T>
struct C {
    typename T::t var;
};

template <typename BaseType>
struct A : public C<BaseType> {
  int i;
};

struct B
{
  typedef int t;
  A<B> a;
};


typedef A<B> AType;

int main() {

  AType a;
  a.i = 1;
  a.var = 1;
  B c;
  c.a.i =0;

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First if you want a class to be a base class, its type must be complete, like

```
struct A : public C<B>
```

in this case `B` must be complete type.

Second, if you declare a class type member its type need to be complete unless you define a pointer.

```
struct B
{
    A a;  // A must be complete type
};
```

So you can't have `A` inheriting from `B` and `B` having in as member. But you could convert one to pointer. For sample, below should be fine:

```
class A;

struct B
{
    A* a;           // imcomplete type is fine
    typedef int t;
};

struct A : public C<B> {         
};
```

Normally if you face this kind of issue, that means there is a design issue in your classes. Maybe you are making `monolith classes`.

If you follow good guide line:

```
1 one class (or function), one responsibility. 
2 Where possible, prefer writing functions as nonmember nonfriends.
```

You will have less this kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks, but this means that I am forced to use `new` just because of a design issue? Or can I get around `new` by putting the class instance somewhere else?

Comment: Normally if you face this kind of issue, that means there is a design issue in your classes. Why do you need to circular include each other?

Comment: `A` needs only the static parts of `B`. I think I could split `B` into static vs non-static. Thanks, I guess it's really a design issue.

Comment: just put static member functions into namespace, make them free functions.